# How to fix frame rate drop issues when using Animation Timer in JavaFX?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, frame-rate

I'm building a game, in order to manage the frames etc, I'm using AnimationTimer, however, I think that when I go below 60FPS, it just starts lagging a lot, making the game very slow.

How can I fix that issue please ?

I tried many things, nothing conclusive. For example I found in another thread that maybe using `System.setProperty("quantum.multithreaded", "false");` was a solution, it was not in my case.

I'm using IntelliJ to run my project, so Java 1.8 is set as the SDK in the Project Structure, if I'm not mistaken then it's Java SDK 8.

Here's the code :

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import controleur.GameManager;
import controleur.SoundManager;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import vue.Vue;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("quantum.multithreaded", "false");
    // Framerate
    int FPS = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getRefreshRate();
    long nbSecPerFrame = Math.round(1.0/FPS * 1e9);

    GameManager.initEtats();
    SoundManager.setVolumes(0.33);

    Vue vue = new Vue();
    primaryStage = vue.initStage(primaryStage);

    //Ce compteur va appeler handle à chaque frame, et handle va demander au GameManager de mettre à jour l'ensemble.
    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        private long lastFrame = 0;
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if ((now - lastFrame)*2 > nbSecPerFrame) {
                GameManager.update();
                lastFrame = now;
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

Thank you

EDIT : Just in case it might be a Linux related issue, I'm using KDE Neon, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx